# How to call a rest API using refit in a xamarin library/sdk

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, refit

I'm building a xamarin library/plugin and the plugin is supposed to call an API using refit but when I call the API I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00110] in <99e6bf9d99304315ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ac] in <99e6bf9d99304315ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00134] in <99e6bf9d99304315ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0
```

My Sdk code:
Interface

```
namespace Plugin.MySDK
{
public interface ISDK
    {
        [Post("/cart")]
        Task<Events> postCart([Body] Events events);
    }
}
```

MySDK.android.cs where I make the api call

```
namespace Plugin.MySDK
{
    public class MySDK 
    {
        static Activity currentActivity;
        private static string _ms = "abcd";
        private static string _appName;

        private static string BASE_URL = "http://b80502ca.ngrok.io";

        public TerraSDK()
        {
        }
        public static void initialize(Activity activity,
            string app)
        {

            currentActivity = activity;
            _appName = app;
        }
        public static async void Cart()
        {
            try
            {
                var apiResponse = RestService.For<ISDK>(BASE_URL);

                Events events = new Events();
                events.ms = _ms;
                events.app = _appName;
                Events ev = await apiResponse.postCart(events);
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + ev);  

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cart:" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Making use of the SDK:

```
namespace TestSdk.Droid
{
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        Button cart;
        private static string _appName = "TestSdk";
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            cart = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cart);
            MySDK.initialize(this,_appName);
            cart.Click += this.Message;
        }
        public void Message(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MySDK.Cart();
        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried calling the API this same way from an app everything works as expected. Please help and correct me if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm new to xamarin

Comment: Did you enable the internet permission in the Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, I even called the same api in the app and it worked fine but didn't work when called it through the sdk

Comment: This should be an issue with a Firewall. Are you able to replicate this issue using Android Device & Emulator & on iOS Device & Simulator as well?

Comment: I was able to replicate it on an android device.@Saamer